# Significado de "lapsus cálami"

Tags: significado

Mientras leía una obra, que me abstendré de mencionar, se menciona la siguiente frase al hacer referencia a otras frases de otras obras.

> Tenía la mano fría como la de una serpiente

Se dice que esta frase es un *lapsus cálami*.

Obviamente *lapsus cálami*, por lo que podemos inferir, hace referencia a un exabrupto. ¿Cuál es el origen de esta frase? ¿Qué significa *cálami*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Lapsus cálami* es una locución latina que literalmente significa "error de pluma".

Gramaticalmente, está formada con el nominativo de *lapsus*, -us (error) y el genitivo de *calamus*, -i (pluma).

El Diccionario de la Real Academia Española [lo describe](http://dle.rae.es/lapsus+calami) como "Error mecánico que se comete al escribir".

Se trata de errores durante la composición de un texto literario; generalmente se producen durante la reordenación de las frases, cuando se agregan o modifican algunas partes que modifican el sentido original.

Answer (score 4):

"Lapsus cálami" es una expresión proveniente del latín (como *vice versa* o *in albis* por ejemplo) que todavía se usa en español y otros idiomas.

"Lapsus cálami" se refiere a un error involuntario al escribir. La expresión "hermana" sería "lapsus linguae" que es una error al hablar.

Para clarificar tu ejemplo, se menciona la frase

> Tenía la mano fría como la de una serpiente

pero por supuesto las serpientes no tienen manos (ni pies). Ese es el "lapsus"

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "cuando haciendo referencia" y "al hacer referencia", como veo que editaste mi pregunta? ¿Es incorrecto decir "cuando haciendo referencia"?

Comment: Básicamente, estás traduciendo literalmente ("when doing a reference") pero en español no usamos el gerundio de la forma en que se usa en inglés, si no que usamos el infinitivo para formas no personales. **Playing** soccer is fun -> **Jugar** al fútbol es divertido (y no _jugando_). **Talking** loud is not allowed in the library -> **Hablar** alto no está permitido en la biblioteca (y no _hablando_).

Comment: Puestos a corregir, el "si no" de tu comentario es un "sino".

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, gracias. Un _lapsus cálami_ (o _lapsus clavis_).

Comment: Una colección de *lapsus calami*: http://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/anteriores/agosto_98/24081998_02.htm